# Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!

Tags: server, fonts, xvfb

I am trying to install xvfb on my ubuntu server(without desktop) in order to run a selenium test case.

I followed this tutorial but while running the below code it showed me error like:

```
root@test-app-java-lo-node01:/etc/apt# Xvfb :99 -ac
    [dix] Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!
```

[image]

Comment: i have same problem